# Why is this piece of code making two fields?

Tags: wordpress, function, woocommerce

The problem is i need a custom field for my buyers to input some dates in a textarea, and when i make the code for it with a plugin or hardcode a function for it, the code makes 2 input fields as shown in this picture/gyazo, i i cant seem to figure out why :/

https://gyazo.com/97e61de41071324491268258d84f8aae

You can see the code in the next gyazo:

https://gyazo.com/e811efd8b0e9c60b361dc52027693797

I have tried everything that i could figure out with my compatebilities

```
//Custom Product Option

function custom_field_by_category() {
    global $product;

    if ( is_product_category( 'work-date' ) ) {
        return;
    }

    ?>
    <div class="custom-date-field">
        <label for="custom-date"><?php _e( 'Engraving (10 characters)', 'iconic' ); ?></label>
        <input type="text" id="custom-date" name="dato_oensker" placeholder="<?php _e( 'Dato Ønsker', 'iconic' ); ?>" maxlength="10">
    </div>
    <?php
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'custom_field_by_category', 10 );
```

Comment: maybe because you are calling `custom_field_by_category()` twice? (Somewhere else in your code)

Comment: @B001ᛦ - I checked for this, and i cant find it anywhere in any code. It does the same if i use a plugin for this the extra product option (I am using wordpres)

Comment: Is this on a variable product? Is your theme's templates out of date (specifically the variation and variable add to cart templates). I've seen 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button` called twice in outdated templates.